# Position of a label

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to proceed to adjust the position of the label E as in the picture ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]  
  \coordinate[label = below left:A] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label = above:B]  (B) at (1,4);
  \coordinate[label = above left:C]  (C) at (8,5);
  \coordinate[label = above right:D] (D) at (9,-2);
  \coordinate[label = left :E] (E) at (3,-3);

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\alpha}{asin(5/8)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{asin(-1)}

 \begin{scope}[thick,red,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt]
   \draw (A)--(B);
   \draw (B)--(C);
   \draw (C)--(D);
   \draw (D)--(E);
   \draw (E)--(A);
   \draw (A)--(C);
   \draw (A)--(D);
   \draw (E)--(C);
 \end{scope}


 \draw[radius=0.5,red,thick] (C) ++({0.5*cos(\alpha)},{0.5*sin(\alpha)}) circle ;

 \draw[radius=0.5,red,thick] (E) ++({0.5*cos(\beta)},{0.5*sin(\beta)}) circle ;

 \begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=blue!50,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
    \foreach \n in {(A), (B), (C), (D), (E)}{
       \node at \n {};
           }
 \end{scope}

 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `label ={[xshift=-5pt] left :E}`

Comment: @Fabrice -- you can use angles also to set the label precisely on the points of a circle --- in the answer below at 180degrees and the label distance is adjusted at 3pts from the coordinate

Comment: @Fabrice -- would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
  \coordinate[label = {[label distance=3pt]180:E}] (E) at (3,-3);
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]  
  \coordinate[label = below left:A] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label = above:B]  (B) at (1,4);
  \coordinate[label = above left:C]  (C) at (8,5);
  \coordinate[label = above right:D] (D) at (9,-2);
  \coordinate[label = {[label distance=3pt]180:E}] (E) at (3,-3);

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\alpha}{asin(5/8)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\beta}{asin(-1)}

 \begin{scope}[thick,red,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt]
   \draw (A)--(B);
   \draw (B)--(C);
   \draw (C)--(D);
   \draw (D)--(E);
   \draw (E)--(A);
   \draw (A)--(C);
   \draw (A)--(D);
   \draw (E)--(C);
 \end{scope}


 \draw[radius=0.5,red,thick] (C) ++({0.5*cos(\alpha)},{0.5*sin(\alpha)}) circle ;

 \draw[radius=0.5,red,thick] (E) ++({0.5*cos(\beta)},{0.5*sin(\beta)}) circle ;

 \begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=blue!50,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
    \foreach \n in {(A), (B), (C), (D), (E)}{
       \node at \n {};
           }
 \end{scope}

 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion